# Emacs does not run after package updating

Tags: emacs

What should I do? After just updating packages my *Emacs* installation does not initialise. I tried the same process in two Macs with the same result. The error message (using `--debug-init`) is:

```
 Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-variable left)
  powerline-reset()
  require(powerline)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-583073> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2361
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit-misc.org")
  starter-kit-load("starter-kit-misc.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-903092> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 3819
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el" nil nil t)
  load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.el")
  org-babel-load-file("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/starter-kit.org")
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 2725
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/sergiobacelar/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\262   \306=\203\307\310Q\202; \311=\204\307\312Q\202;\313\307\314\315#\203*\316\202;\313\307\314\317#\203:\320\nB\321\202;\316\322\323\322\211#\210\322=\203a\324\325\326\307\327Q!\"\323\322\211#\210\322=\203`\210\203\243\330!\331\232\203\243\332!\211\333P\334!\203}\211\202\210\334!\203\207\202\210\314\262\203\241\335\"\203\237\336\337#\210\340\341!\210\266\f?\205\260\314\323\342\322\211#)\262\207" [init-file-user system-type delayed-warnings-list user-init-file inhibit-default-init inhibit-startup-screen ms-dos "~" "/_emacs" windows-nt "/.emacs" directory-files nil "^\\.emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" "~/.emacs" "^_emacs\\(\\.elc?\\)?$" (initialization "`_emacs' init file is deprecated, please use `.emacs'") "~/_emacs" t load expand-file-name "init" file-name-as-directory "/.emacs.d" file-name-extension "elc" file-name-sans-extension ".el" file-exists-p file-newer-than-file-p message "Warning: %s is newer than %s" sit-for 1 "default"] 7 "\n\n(fn)"]()
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

Comment: You may want to consider migration to [Emacs.SE](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I will do that. It was unknown to me.

Comment: FYI: It's good to know about Emacs.SE, but there is no need to migrate your question there.

Comment: It looks like function `powerline-reset` is trying to evaluate an unbound variable named `left`. There is not enough information posted in your question to know more than this. Either take a look at the `powerline.el` code or contact its author/maintainer for assistance.

Comment: You can post your solution - even if it is just a pointer to a known bug - as an answer. And you can accept your own answer. That makes it clear what the answer is, and it will save some people looking here to try to help you out etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a solution for this in `https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/79`. It seems to be a known bug in `powerline.el`.